# Why use service for background music in android

Tags: android, service

Why should service be used for playing background music in Android? Why not I just create another media player object loop the player to play the music?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keyword is `background`. If you tie your Media Player object to an activity, you don't have  the guarantee that your object will be around if your activity goes to the background. The GC will destroy it when resources become low.
Therefore using a Service is safer. And services are designed for running in the background unlike activities.

Comment: I have three different screens and I want to play different BG for each. And I need to handle lot of things when I use service like when the user clicks on Home button, when the app is closed. back button... when I receive calls and more.

I can hear the music sometimes when I restart my app. :(

Just wondering can I just use mediaplayer and release it when ever not required.